# UPDATE Statement with right join

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
 select  A.GEO_COORDINATE_RID , B.GEO_COORDINATE_RID 
 from FAC_FACILITY as A
 right join SYS_GEO_COORDINATE as B
 on  A.CREATED_DATE= B.CREATED_DATE
 where B.CREATED_BY = 'EPDMIG'
```

Above select statement gives 340 results, but when I'm trying to use in update statement (below) , its gives 0 results

```
 update A
 set A. GEO_COORDINATE_RID = B.GEO_COORDINATE_RID
 from FAC_FACILITY as A
 right join SYS_GEO_COORDINATE as B
 on  A.CREATED_DATE= B.CREATED_DATE
 where B.CREATED_BY = 'EPDMIG'
```

GEO_COORDIANTE _RID From sys_GEO_COORDIANTE is FK on FAC_FACILITY table

is there any missing in update statement ?

Comment: GEO_COORDIANTE _RID From sys_GEO_COORDIANTE is FK on FAC_FACILITY table

Comment: What is with the space in "A. GEO_COORDINATE_RID"?

Comment: If you replace the RIGHT JOIN with INNER JOIN how rows you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a RIGHT JOIN which means there could be no rows matched for A.  How many A.GEO_COORDINATE_RID are null?  All of them?  If you do just a JOIN, do any rows come back?

Second item, if CREATED_DATE is a DateTime then they have to match down to the millisecond. Not sure what you are doing, but you could join on the day like below if you only care about the day. But having said that, it is not normally done that you join on a create_date. Should you be joining on GEO_COORDINATE_RID?

```
select  A.GEO_COORDINATE_RID , B.GEO_COORDINATE_RID 
 from FAC_FACILITY as A
 join SYS_GEO_COORDINATE as B
 on  CAST(A.CREATED_DATE AS DATE) = CAST(B.CREATED_DATE AS DATE)
 where B.CREATED_BY = 'EPDMIG'
```